# Prove that $ \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^3 + y^6} = 0 $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to show that
$$
\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^3 + y^6} = 0
$$
Unfortunately, I am stuck in the math. I tried squeeze theorem, and $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ but unsuccessfully.

Any suggestions on approaches?

Comment: Try the limits along the paths $t\mapsto (kt^2,t)$ with $k\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Apply Cauchy inequality for the denominator

Answer (score 2):

Is false: the quotient isn't defined in the subset $x^3+y^6 = 0$, i.e., $x = -y^2$.

EDIT: [Wolfram Alpha does the limit definitely wrong](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=2958433016861a528d6221f5ac88eefd). An even excluding the bad subset,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(-1/n^2,1/n+1/n^2) = \infty.$$

Comment: This is peculiar...WolframAlpha tells me this evaluates to 0. What might be the issue?

Comment: @OrestXherija, I will check later.